# ultisnips gives me an error message in Vim: E117: Unknown function: UltiSnips#

Tags: vim, debian, debian-buster, ultisnips

I've got the next error when trying to use ultisnips plugin in vim.

vim starts but the message appears every time I to run several commands in vim.

E117: Unknown function: UltiSnips#FileTypeChanged

I'm using:

- Debian 10 Buster
- vim-plug to manage automatically the vim plugins

After searching for solutions all looked old and none of them applied in my case.

Eventually I could solve it doing the next. Just writing it here including the solution that eventually worked.

Answer (score 4):

I found that the plugin was also installed by apt-get, so I removed
that plugin installed by apt-get, and also unneeded remaining packages:

```
>$ apt-get remove --purge vim-ultisnips vim-snippets
>$ apt-get autoremove
```

Also, I got the next warning:
«/var/lib/vim/addons/pythonx/UltiSnips/snippet» not empty, so not deleted.
and deleted it manually

After that, I could start vim, got no errors and ultisnips was working fine.

Regards,

Comment: This solution worked for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS